# Why do I get an entry into the dblclick handler when double click was not issued?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/eF5cp/5/) with a resizable box. When double-clicking anywhere on the document, the box color toggles between beige and red.

The problem is that sometimes when releasing the left mouse button after resizing the box, a `dblclick` event is generated and the box turns red. And sometimes you can release the mouse button without changing the box color, but then if you click just once in the box it generates the `dblclick` and changes the box color.

Usually, everything works fine: I resize and there's no `dblclick` entry. I have to try maybe 20 times to get a false `dblclick` event.

I'm using Chrome.

I could partially fix this particular instance of the problem by adding code to the `dblclick` handler to ignore the entry if a resize is in progress. That still doesn't fix the `dblclick` entry, though, that happens (very rarely)  when I resize , get no `dblclick`, but then get a `dblclik` when I click just once in the box.

But rather than just get the JSFiddle here to work, what I'm looking for here is the reason this `dblclick` is generated. Am I using the `dblclick` event incorrectly? Is there a known bug with this event and perhaps a better solution? Is there some kind of switch bounce going on with the mouse button?

```
$(function() {
    $("#box").resizable();
    $(document).dblclick(function(e){
        console.log("double-clicked on ",  e.target);
        $("#box").toggleClass("red");
    });
});
```

Comment: I was only able to reproduce it if I double clicked when the 2nd click inits a resize, and I'm also using Chrome.

Comment: This error are you talking about doesn't appear.

Comment: Works well on Mac (Safari, Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: For me, it only does (in FF) when 1. left click and release, 2. immediately left click again and hold, 3. resize the div, 4. release the mouse button. And this in really short time. The browser is probably 'saving' the first click for a short period of time, and when the resize is done it registers the second click, thinking: ah, doubleclick. Somehow you should delete the first click when resizing.

Answer (score 2):

It can be related to your hardware, I guess it is also affected by your system's "double click delay" setting.

Using Firefox, if I repeatedly click&drag with small, close motions, I do trigger the dblclick event, and I would say it is normal behaviour. I don't see dblclicks poping out of nowhere with 5 secs spaced clicks, though.

To help you track a possible cause for your bug, try to also log the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events :

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    console.log("    mousedown on ",  e.target);
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    console.log("    mouseup on ",  e.target);
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eF5cp/10/)

Comment: I don't think that what I'm seeing is normal behavior. I can click, drag, reszie, etc. (which all work fine) and then maybe 3 seconds later the next click is a dblclick. The system seems to be storing up one of the earlier operations as a first click. I'm using a lot of jQuery, so maybe there's a bug in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 $('#test').dblclick(function(e){
 if(!$(e.target).is('.ui-resizable-handle'))
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  }).resizable();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmvDs/10/)

Comment: Yes, I could do the dblclick action only if the dblclick was NOT on a ui-resizable-handle.  But what I'm looking for is why the dblclick is even generated when you resize something.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in chrome too and it works fine for me... It does not trigger if you click too close to a dbclick, like the event does not fire as it dosent recognize the dbclick as you clicking too fast. That's the best answer I can give. I have some problems with my mouse sometimes, if I dont click too hard it doesn't register a mouseclick... but my mouse is pretty old, not sure if your mouse works perfectly :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop click handler for resize handles using stoppropagation.
Updated the jsfiddle and tested.

```
$(function() {
    $("#box").resizable();
    $(".ui-resizable-handle").dblclick(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    })
    $(document).dblclick(function(e){
        console.log("double-clicked on ",  e.target);
        $("#box").toggleClass("red");
    });

});
```